# Skipping lines in android java strings

Tags: java, android

```
  Giveaway Updates - v1.0.0  ------------------------------------- Application has been created---------------------------------------
```

I checked the application in the emulator. There is exactly 4 dashes in the same line as giveaway updates in which i wanted to only have giveaway updates there. 
It looks like this ATM

```
Giveaway Updates - v1.0.0----
-----------------------------
Application has been created-
-----------------------------
```

how can i make it so it would be like this?

```
Giveaway Updates - v1.0.0
-----------------------------
Application has been created
-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
public String changeFormat(String myString) {
    String[] lines = myString.split("-[-]+"); // split everytime there are two or more '-'
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(myString.length());
    for (String line in lines) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append('\n');
        sb.append("-----------------------------");
        sb.append('\n');
    }
    return sb.toString()
}
```